# How to change key value in the nested object array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I would like to know how to change the value in a nested object array using javascript.

how to change the `"load": "undefined"` to `"load":1` in the `obj`

```
var obj=[{
  "id": "service",
  "country": "AR",
  "load": "undefined"
},{
  "id": "fund",
  "country": "CA",
  "load": "undefined"
}]


var result = obj.forEach(e=>e.load=1);

Expected Output:
[{
  "id": "service",
  "country": "AR",
  "load": 1
},{
  "id": "fund",
  "country": "CA",
  "load": 1
}]
```

Comment: Why the two key names are different `load` and `loading`

Comment: Your code works. The only issue is that `forEach` doesn't return anything - you're instead changing `obj` in-place, so you can just return that, if needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this easily with new ES2015+ syntax.  Using the spread operator:

```
var result = obj.map(e => ({ ...e, load: 1 }));
```

This will keep all the other props and only change `load` to what you want.

Also, FYI - `[].forEach()` does not work this way.

Answer (score 2):

`forEach` does not return anything,your code is working fine so in your code the original object that is `obj` will be changed and if you log it show `load:1`. If you don't want to change original array use map which returns a new array

```js
var obj = [{
  "id": "service",
  "country": "AR",
  "load": "undefined"
}, {
  "id": "fund",
  "country": "CA",
  "loading": "undefined"
}]


var result = obj.map(function(elem) {
  return Object.assign({}, elem, {
    // only change to 1 if value is undefined
    load: elem.load === 'undefined' ? 1 : elem.load 
  })

});
console.log(result)
```